# Finding out if two points are on the same side

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a definite line segment and then am given two random different points, how would i be able to determine if they are on the same side of the line segment?
I am wanting to use a function def same_side (line, p1, p2). I know based on geometry that cross products can be used but am unsure how to do so with python.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get the equation of the line in slope-intercept form, you should be able to set up an inequality.
Say we have points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), and the line y = mx+b

You should be able to plug in the x and y values for both points, and if both make the equation y < mx + b or both make it y > mx + b, they are on the same side.
If either point satisfies the equation (y = mx + b), that point is on the line.

`if (y1 > m * x1 + b and y2 > m * x2 + b) or (y1 < m * x1 + b and y2 < m *x2 + b):
    return True #both on same side`

Answer (score 4):

Based on the tutorial [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162728/how-to-determine-if-2-points-are-on-opposite-sides-of-a-line):

```
def same_side (line, p1, p2):
         return ((line['y1']−line['y2'])*(p1['x']−line['x1'])+(line['x2']−line['x1'])*(p1['y']−line['y1']))*((line['y1']−line['y2'])*(p2['x']−line['x1'])+(line['x2']−line['x1'])*(p2['y']−line['y1']))>0
```

Example:

```
# Same side
 line = {'x1':0,'y1':0,'x2':1,'y2':1} 
 p1 = {'x':0,'y':1}
 print same_side (line, p1, p1)

# Same side
 line = {'x1':0,'y1':0,'x2':1,'y2':1} 
 p1 = {'x':0,'y':1}
 p2 = {'x':0,'y':2} 
 print same_side (line, p1, p2)

# Different side
 line = {'x1':0,'y1':0,'x2':1,'y2':1} 
 p1 = {'x':0,'y':1}
 p2 = {'x':0,'y':-2} 
 print same_side (line, p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the line segment's endpoints (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), the [equation for the line passing through them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) is y = y1 + (x - x1)/(x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1).  Points above the line will have larger y values and points below will have smaller y values.  So you simply have to plug each query point's x value into this formula, which gives you the y-coordinate of the line at that x, and compare it to the query point's x.  If both points are on the same side, their x's will both be larger or both be smaller.

The one exception to this is when the line is perfectly vertical (x1 == x2).  Here the formula breaks down, so you'll need a special case to check for this.  In this case, compare the x-coordinates of the query points to the x-coordinate of the line (x1 or x2, doesn't matter which).

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy available, this is as simple as:

```
import numpy as np

def same_side(line, point1, point2):
    v1 = np.array([line.start.x - line.end.x, line.start.y - line.end.y])
    v2 = np.array([line.start.x - point1.x, line.start.y - point1.y])
    v3 = np.array([line.start.x - point2.x, line.start.y - point1.y])
    return (np.dot(np.cross(v1, v2), np.cross(v1, v3)) >= 0)
```